# How to combine lists with plus minus signs?

Tags: output-formatting

I have two lists of Mathematica expressions,

```
t1 = {(-2*wr20)/(7*Sqrt[15]) + (10*Sqrt[3]*wr40)/77 - (50*wr60)/(11*Sqrt[39]), 
       wr00 - (Sqrt[5]*wr20)/3};  

t2 = {(2*wr20)/(7*Sqrt[15]) - (10*Sqrt[3]*wr40)/77 + (50*wr60)/(11*Sqrt[39]), 
       wr00 - (Sqrt[5]*wr20)/3};
```

where one of the terms is the same, the other differs by an overall sign, and they have the same ordering. What I want is to combine the two lists and output to latex using $\pm$ and $\mp$ signs, like
$$\left\{\mp\frac{2 \text{wr20}}{7 \sqrt{15}}\pm\frac{10 \sqrt{3} \text{wr40}}{77}\mp\frac{50 \text{wr60}}{11
   \sqrt{39}},\text{wr00}-\frac{\sqrt{5} \text{wr20}}{3}\right\}.$$
This is just a simplified example of large lists I'm dealing with. The terms that differ by overall signs are alway at the same positions in the lists. It will save a lot of space in the latex document by combining them. There is some discussion about $\pm$ signs, but none could solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[syntaticSigns, removeSigns, combineByAbs]

syntaticSigns = Map[(-1)^Boole[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ @ #] &] /@ MonomialList @ # &;

removeSigns = Abs[#] /. Abs -> Identity &;

combineByAbs = If[StringStartsQ["+"] @ #, StringDrop[#, 1], #] & /@ Values @ 
   GroupBy[Join[##], Abs@*MonomialList, 
      StringJoin @ Riffle[Transpose[syntaticSigns[#]] /. 
         { {-1, 1} -> "∓", {1, -1} -> "±", {-1, -1} -> "\[Minus]", {1, 1} -> "+"}, 
         ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ removeSigns[MonomialList @ First @ #]] &] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
combineByAbs[t1, t2]
```

[image]

```
ToExpression[combineByAbs[t1, t2]]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ ToExpression[combineByAbs[t1, t2]]
```

> $\left\{\left(\mp \frac{2 \text{wr20}}{7 \sqrt{15}}\pm \frac{10 \sqrt{3}
>    \text{wr40}}{77}\right)\mp \frac{50 \text{wr60}}{11
>    \sqrt{39}},\text{wr00}-\frac{\sqrt{5} \text{wr20}}{3}\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

The following adds an additional "+" sign before the "+/-" and reorders the additive terms according to MMA rules. Is this acceptable?

```
t1 = {(-2*wr20)/(7*Sqrt[15]) + (10*Sqrt[3]*wr40)/
     77 - (50*wr60)/(11*Sqrt[39]), wr00 - (Sqrt[5]*wr20)/3};
t2 = {(2*wr20)/(7*Sqrt[15]) - (10*Sqrt[3]*wr40)/
     77 + (50*wr60)/(11*Sqrt[39]), wr00 - (Sqrt[5]*wr20)/3};

fun[x1_, x2_] := Plus @@ MapThread[
    If[#1 === #2, #,
      If[Positive[#1 /. c_?NumericQ  x_ -> c], PlusMinus[#1], 
       MinusPlus[#2]]
      ] &, {List @@ x1, List @@ x2}];
MapThread[fun, {t1, t2}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a step forward. It would be better if you could remove the unwanted $+$ sign.

Comment: It produces  output  {\[PlusMinus](-((2 wr20)/(7 Sqrt[15]))) + \[PlusMinus]((
   10 Sqrt[3] wr40)/77) + \[PlusMinus](-((50 wr60)/(11 Sqrt[39]))), 
 wr00 - (Sqrt[5] wr20)/3}.  TeXForm gives the same form, so it's not really useful.